# attempt to call unbound fn

Tags: clojure, apache-storm, streamparse

In my case, streamparse api were used to run locally and submit code to STORM cluster, when I ran it locally it was ok but when it is submitted to STORM cluster, I got

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn

clojure version is 1.5.1, storm version is 0.9.5, sparse 2.1.3

the error was due to calling "call-to-outside-function" within spout execute, and that function can be 3rd party library as well, the code is as follows:

```
(defn call-to-outside-function [someArg](do stuff ....))

(defspout kw-spout ["something"]
  [conf context collector]
        (spout
            (nextTuple []
                (call-to-outside-function "someArgs")
                (emit-spout! collector ("not important"))
                )
            (ack [id])
            ))
```

Anyone has this issue before ?

Comment: Is the definition of `call-to-outside-function` in the classpath somewhere?

Comment: Where is this clojure function called from..? Is it via some other clojure function or through other API e.g. java code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure deftype calling function in the same namespace throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn:"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953621/clojure-deftype-calling-function-in-the-same-namespace-throws-java-lang-illegal)